# Do not include https endpoints if IIS server does not support them

Tags: wix, installation, config, xml

How I can comment element of config file during the installing?
I.e. I install WCF service to IIS. If IIS does not have https protocol binding I need to comment https endpoints in Web.config. 
Else do not comment this endpoint.

```
  <service name="MyServer.MyDataAccessRESTService" behaviorConfiguration="MyServer.MyDataAccessRESTServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" contract="MyServer.IMyDataAccessRESTService" 
              bindingConfiguration="webHttpBinding0" behaviorConfiguration="MyDataAccessRESTServiceBehavior" 
              address="http://localhost/svc2Web/svc2rest.svc"></endpoint>
    <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" contract="MyServer.IMyDataAccessRESTService"
              bindingConfiguration="webHttpBinding1" behaviorConfiguration="MyDataAccessRESTServiceBehavior"
              address="https://localhost/svc2Web/svc2rest.svc"></endpoint>
  </service>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this the other way around. Let the default version of web.config omit the HTTPS endpoint. In case HTTPS is on in IIS, add a new element to web.config using XmlConfig capabilities. You can find the sample of how to do this [here](http://wix.mindcapers.com/wiki/WiX_XmlConfig) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gisenberg/archive/2007/10/09/wix-v3-and-xmlconfig-xmlfile-troubleshooting.aspx).

Comment: Thnx, as a one of ways.. There is one disadvantage. I do not know exact string in installer. I know only http or/and https I need. This string contains more elements...